# Fetching image from google using dom

Tags: php, html, image, dom

I want to fetch image from google using PHP. so I tried to get help from net I got a script as I needed but it is showing this fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\nq\qimages.php on line 7**

Here is my script:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$search_query = "car";
$search_query = urlencode( $search_query );
$html = file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/search?q=$search_query&tbm=isch" );
$image_container = $html->find('div#rcnt', 0);
$images = $image_container->find('img');
$image_count = 10; //Enter the amount of images to be shown
$i = 0;
foreach($images as $image){
    if($i == $image_count) break;
    $i++;
    // DO with the image whatever you want here (the image element is '$image'):
    echo $image;
}
?>
```

I am also using [Simple html dom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example that works and gets first image from google results:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.google.hr/search?q=aaaa&biw=1517&bih=714&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIyKnjyrjQyAIVylwaCh06nAIE&dpr=0.9";
$content = file_get_contents($url);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$images_dom = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images_dom as $img) {
    if($img->hasAttribute('src')){
        $image_url = $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
    break;
}


//this is first image on url
echo $image_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that $html isn't an object.

It's odd that you say this seems to work. What happens if you output $html? I'd imagine that the url isn't available and that $html is null.

Edit: Looks like this may be an error in the parser. Someone has submitted a [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/42/) and added a check in his code as a workaround.

Comment: Directly fetch the img tag $image_container = $html->->find('img');

Comment: thanks I have solved the error with the reference given by you but now simple html dom is giving this error:- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED) in C:\wamp\www\nq\simple_html_dom.php on line 1506